# How to parse JSON in android or getdata and intent to other activity?

Tags: android

extra_images: [
{
url: "*.png"
},
{
url: "*.png"
},
{
url: "*.png"
}
]

```
JSONArray extra_images = details.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("extra_images");

for (int m = 0; m < extra_images.length(); m++) { 
    url = extra_images.getJSONObject(m).getString("url");
}
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: This type of JSONArray can not be intent in other activity? How to do this?

Comment: i.putStringArrayListExtra("urlList",requestdataArrayList.get(position).get("urlList"));  it is not okeay with...so

Comment: Do not send the json array string to the intent. You have to first parse it and store in an appropriate data structure and then pass that data into intent.

Answer (score 0):

To put data in intent use `intent.putExtra`, to parse JSON use the classes `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` as needed, to retrieve data inside Intent extras use `intent.get*Extra`

Comment: i.putStringArrayListExtra("ulist",**requestdata.get(position).get("url")**); still error inside bold their Error:String can not be converted in ArrayList<String> i need they are convert....How can we handle this

Comment: You have written way too little code , i wouldn't understand

Comment: JSONArray extra_images = details.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("extra_images");

                    for (int m = 0; m < extra_images.length(); m++) {

                        url = extra_images.getJSONObject(m).getString("url");


                    }
then i.putStringArr.....

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();
JSONArray extra_images = details.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("extra_images");

for (int m = 0; m < extra_images.length(); m++) { 
     urlList.add(extra_images.getJSONObject(m).getString("url"));
}

//declare your intent here
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("intent_key",urlList);
```

Then in your target activity, retrieve the data using

```
ArrayList<String> urlList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("intent_key");
```